# Not able to start computer; hard disk gives disk read error

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have 250GB Seagate Serial ATA hard disk which was giving disk read errors few days ago.

Now my computer fails to start completely.  I checked my disk by making as secondary on another computer, even then master comp was unable to start, what would be the problem?

When I connect the my disk as secondary on other computer the device manager section detects but doesn't show any partitions.

Is my data still there OR have I lost my data? Can I recover my data from HD?

Comment: Although this question is very difficult to understand, it sounds like the drive has failed completely. You may have lost your data. You can send it to a data recovery service to see if they can recover anything for you.

Comment: I agree with @CharlieRB.  You appear to be experiencing what is known as a 'catastrophic failure'.  Your best bet is to get it to a data recovery service like he mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Live Linux CD, like Knoppix, and see if it can see your data.  It's possible that the partition table is messed up, but your data may still be available.  If that is the case, back up your data, and reformat your hard drive.